# What is the difference between list(a) and [a]?

Tags: python, string, list, constructor

I noticed a strange difference between two list constructors that I believed to be equivalent.

Here is a small example:

```
hello = 'Hello World'

first = list(hello)
second = [hello]

print(first)
print(second)
```

This code will produce the following output:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
['Hello World']
```

So, the difference is quite clear between the two constructors... And, I guess that this could be generalized to other constructors as well, but I fail to understand the logic behind it.

Can somebody cast its lights upon my interrogations?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list

Comment: Try `[x for x in hello]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `list()` constructor function takes exactly *one* argument, which must be an *iterable*. It returns a new list with each element being an element from the given iterable. Since strings are iterable (by character), a list with individual characters is returned.

`[]` takes as many "arguments" as you like, each being a single element in the list; the items are not "evaluated" or iterated, they are taken as is.

Everything [as documented](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-list).

Answer (score 2):

The first just transform the list "Hello world" (an character array) into a list

```
first = list(hello)
```

The second create a list with element inside brackets.

```
first = [hello]
```

In the second case for example you could also do:

```
first = [hello, 'hi', 'world']
```

and as output of the print you will get

```
['Hello World', 'hi', 'world']
```

Comment: Slight nitpick: `list()` doesn't transform anything; it simply creates a new list with the given iterable.

Answer (score 1):

your "first" uses the list method, which takes in hello and treats it as an iterable, converting it to a list. Which is why each chararcter is seperate.

your "second" creates a new list, using the string as its value

Answer (score 1):

You are assuming that `list(hello)` should create a list containing one element, the object referred to by `hello`. That's not true; by that logic you would expect `list(5)` to return `[5]`. `list` takes a single *iterable* argument (a list, a tuple, a string, a dict, etc) and returns a list whose elements are taken from the given iterable.

The bracket notation, however, is not limited to containing a single item. Each comma-separated object is treated as a distinct element for the new list.

Answer (score 1):

The most important distinction of these 2 behaviours comes when you work with generators. Given that Python 3 transformed things like `map` and `zip` into generators ...

If we assume `map` returns generators:

```
a = list(map(lambda x: str(x), [1, 2, 3]))
print(a)
```

The result is:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

But if we do:

```
a = [map(lambda x: str(x), [1, 2, 3])]
print(a)
```

The result is:

```
[<map object at 0x00000209231CB2E8>]
```

It is obvious that the 2nd case is in most situations undesirable and not expected.

P.S.
If you are in Python 2, then do at the beginning:  `from itertools import imap as map`

Answer (score 0):

```
first = list(hello)
```

converts a string into a list.

```
second = [hello]
```

this places an item into a new list. it is not a constructor